# Getting 403 (Forbidden) when upload a file to S3 by using presigned url

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, pre-signed-url

I'm a newbie and I'm getting used to AWS S3, my idea is using Python to generate signed url and use JS in front-end to upload a file via that url.
I use Python to generate a presigned url by boto3, here is my code :

```
from flask_cors import CORS
import boto3
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/get-signed-url', methods=['POST'])
def get_signed_url():
    s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id='***',  
        aws_secret_access_key='***'  
    )

    # Lấy dữ liệu từ yêu cầu POST
    data = request.get_json()
    name = data.get('name')

    # Thiết lập tham số cho URL
    params = {
        'Bucket': 'myprojecttt',  
        'Key': name,
        'Expires': 30 * 60, 
    }

    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object',
        Params=params
    )

    return jsonify({'url': url})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my front-end script:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
  <button onclick="fetchData()">Upload</button>

  <script>
    async function fetchData() {

      const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      const file = fileInput.files[0];
      console.log(file)

      if (!file) {
        alert("Please select a file.");
        return;
      }

      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/get-signed-url', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ name: file.name }), // Gửi tên tệp đến máy chủ
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Thiết lập kiểu nội dung của yêu cầu
          },
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        const presignedUrl = data.url;
        console.log('Presigned URL:', presignedUrl);

        try {
          const response = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: file,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': file.type,
            },
          });

          if (response.ok) {
            console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
          } 
          // else {
          //   console.error('Error:', response.status, response.statusText);
          // }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    } 
  </script>
```

So when I choose a file to upload I got "PUT url 403 (Forbidden)" and I think the code block making error is :

```
const response = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: file,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': file.type,
            },
```

Let me know if you need information. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The most obvious reason that the upload fails with 403 is that the AWS credentials your script is using do not have permission to upload objects to that S3 bucket. Have you checked the IAM policy associated with the credentials?

Comment: I've created a user called "quockhanh" and attached policy "AmazonS3FullAccess" then I used accessKey of "quockhanh". I don't know if that's enough

Comment: It's necessary but may not be sufficient. Does the S3 bucket have a bucket policy? If so, add it to your question. Independently of that, verify that you can upload to the S3 bucket using your credentials *outside* of your application. I'd suggest using the awscli for that e.g. `aws s3 cp cat.png s3://myprojecttt/cat.png`.